# changing input icon color in react-native-elements

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I want to change input icon color in react-native-elements, I am trying like this:

```
<Input
      placeholder="password"
      secureTextEntry={true}
      leftIconContainerStyle={{'color': 'red'}}
      leftIcon={{ type: "font-awesome", name: "lock" }}
    />
```

But this is not working. Please help

Answer (score 0):

just add the color in the leftIcon prop

```
leftIcon={{ type: "font-awesome", name: "lock", color: 'red'}}
```